# How to differentiate strings in collectd?

Tags: csv, plugins, influxdb, grafana, collectd

I am actually working with Collectd and Influxdb to graph data in Grafana.

The data I get in python is saved in a .csv file, so am using tail_csv plugin in collectd to get data from this .csv file.

Everything is okay and the data is sent to influxdb but I want to differentiate data from different devices.

For example, I got this :

```
Data from device 1 in csv format: 0,0,0,0,0
                                  0,0,0,0,0

Data from device 2 in csv format: 0,0,0,0,0
                                  0,0,0,0,0

In the final csv file will be next: 0,0,0,0,0
                                    0,0,0,0,0
                                    0,0,0,0,0
                                    0,0,0,0,0
```

Collectd don't have string type, so I can't add a string column to know where the data's from. How can I solve it?

**My possible solutions**: Not to use a string column but yes an int column, and associate each int to a device, but the possible devices are dynamic so I don't like it. 
I also think about writing one tail_csv plugin code per device, so when a new device is detected, a new plugin code will be written to read a new .csv file per device, but it is very heavy.

Please advise !

Answer (score 0):

Collectd supports data paths of the form:

```
host/plugin-instance/type-instance
```

For simplicity:

```
a/b-c/TYPE-d
```

or

```
a/b/TYPE-c
```

so you can freely choose a, b, c, and d.

I am not sure what your paths look like based on the information provided. You could use "b" in the last example to denote the device name.

Alternatively name the entry something like a/b/TYPE-_whatever_DEVICE_NUM and use one of Graphite's aliasSub() to pick out the devices and display them separately, if that's what you want to do.